# Column Series type to String

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have the below code that tries to change a code if something happens in other column:

```
for idx,row in df_control.iterrows():
    if 'VAP' in df_control.at[idx,'APPOINTMENT']:
        df_control.at[idx,'COD_OF'] == 'eee'
    elif 'SVE' in df_control.at[idx,'APPOINTMENT']:
         df_control.at[idx,'COD_OF'] == 'AA'
```

The problem is when i try to change:  `df_control.at[idx,'COD_OF']` doesnt change,

The type of the column is = `pandas.core.series.Series`

To obtain the code I made the below for loop, that join data from another dataframe, the problem is that somethins the join bring two results:

```
df_control.at[idx,'COD_OF'] = cod_sup['COD_OF'][cod_sup['RUT_EMISOR'] == df_control.at[idx,'RUT_EMISOR']].to_string(index=False).strip()
```

So how I can fix this? The problem is the join? or the problem is the first for loop?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you're using `==` which is a comparison operation ***NOT*** assignment.  Use a single `=` instead.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank u so much, i ddint see that simple error, thanks